# Counting problem with numbered deck of cards, probability one card is exactly double another

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've recently purchased a book I assume has an incorrect solution to this problem. I wanted to run my solution by you

> Assume you have a deck of 100 cards with values ranging from 1 to 100 and that you draw two cards at random without replacement. What is probability one card is precisely double that of the other?

My solution:

- Assume first card can be double or second card can be double
- If first card is double it can be any even number (50 choices)
- If first card is double, second card has 1/99 probability of being the half-card

So for the first card to be double, the probability is: `50 * 1/100 * 1/99`
For the second card to be double, we simply double our total probability.

So the probability of drawing two cards, where one is double the other, is: `2 * 1/2 * 1/99` or `0.0101`

Can someone let me know if I'm correct?

The book's solution is double this, saying since order does not matter there are exactly `50 * 2 = 100` ways to draw such a pair. So the desired probability is `100/(100 choose 2)`.

Comment: This is fine, what was the official solution?  As an alternate way  to look at it (more of a minor variant really) , there are $50$ pairs in which one member is twice the other.  Thus the answer is $50\big / \binom {100}2=\frac 1{99}$.

Comment: Yes, this sounds good to me.  Equivalently, there are $50$ valid pairs where order doesn't matter with one card double the other and there are $\binom{100}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose a pair of cards with order not mattering.  The probability is then $\dfrac{50}{\binom{100}{2}}$ which can be seen to be equal to what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks. The book says: there are exactly 50 pairs that satisfy the condition (1,2).. (50,100) and since order does not matter there are exactly 50 * 2 = 100 ways to draw such a pair. So the desired probability is 100/(100 choose 2). This is incorrect?

Comment: That is indeed incorrect.  They are first respecting the order (in saying that there are $100$ good pairs, and not just $50$), but they then ignore the order (in saying that there are only $\binom {100}2$ possible pairs).

Comment: As a general suggestion:  one easy way to settle points like this is to to do the problem for smaller collections.  Take $2$ cards instead of $100$....their method gives a probability of $2$, your method correctly gives $1$.  You could work the case of $3$ or $4$ cards if you think the $2$ card case is degenerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are $\binom{100}{2}=4950$ ways to get possible pairs with only 50 favourable pairs thus the solution is

$$\frac{50}{4950}=\frac{1}{99}$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes your answer is correct and the previous answer is simpler to go by. Alternatively we can count them as,

All even numbers in the first fifty have two possible choices for the second while all odd numbers in the first fifty have one choice for the second. Coming to the second fifty ($51-100$), all even numbers have one choice for the second whereas odd numbers would not work.

So the probability is,

$ = \displaystyle \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{99} + \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{99} = \frac{1}{99}$